# Declare variable in template table

Tags: hana, sap-data-services

I am writing an ETL to extract data from HANA table and load into SQL Server in BODS.

My job is to create a new table on SQL Server every time I run my job with name as date of that day. I know we can do that for flat files by using global variable but not sure how we can declare similar variable in template table to get desired results?

Answer (score 0):

Why you want to use template tables. You can do the same as below:

1. Load the data in a standard staging table using BODS
2. Using DS scripting mechanism generate a query to create a table
3. Execute the query using SQL transform
4. Generate another query to copy data from staging table to the table created above

Several other ways also like you can write a DB procedure to create a table with the desired name and copy over the data from stage to that table. This procedure you can call from DS.

Hope this helps.

Cheers.
Shaz